# Search(by a givenID) method returning only first object

Tags: java

**Search by id method:**

```
public class ClientsDetailsList {



     public ArrayList <ClientDetails> aListOfClientDetails;



public ClientDetails getClientDetails(String givenID) {
        boolean found = false;
        int index = 0;

        for(;index<aListOfClientDetails.size();index++){
               if((aListOfClientDetails.get(index).ClientID.equals(givenID)))
                  found = true;

        }


        if(found)
        return aListOfClientDetails.get(index);

        else return null;

    }

}
```

**aListOfClientDetails List format** It reads a file and creates a list of ClientDetails.

```
[IC-x00042W Ms LQ Bethea 205, Willis Road Bolton BO5 1DQ 2000000007 2000100037 2006200319,
 IC-x00033D Mr R Bowie 119, Thatcher Way Glasgow GL9 5SX 2006000016 2003100008 2005300001,
 IC-x00013A MS GRV Blackwell 209, Drunk Road Hawick HK8 1MY 2006000009 2004100014 2003200304,
 IC-x00018O Ms NAP Wallis 244, Grubb Lane Durham DU4 4ZX 2000000006 2003100012 2006200305]
```

One line is an object of the list. With the method above I try to return an object of the list found by ID (e.g. first token IC-x00042W). However when I run this in my main method it returns **Only** the first object.(IC-x00042W/Ms/LQ/Bethea/205, Willis Road/Bolton/BO5.....) 
If I search by id of another object it returns null.

**Source of ClientDetailsList:**

The txt file has the following data:

```
IC-x00042W/Ms/LQ/Bethea/205, Willis Road/Bolton/BO5 1DQ/2000000007/2000100037/2006200319#
IC-x00033D/Mr/R/Bowie/119, Thatcher Way/Glasgow/GL9 5SX/2006000016/2003100008/2005300001#
IC-x00013A/MS/GRV/Blackwell/209, Drunk Road/Hawick/HK8 1MY/2006000009/2004100014/2003200304#
IC-x00018O/Ms/NAP/Wallis/244, Grubb Lane/Durham/DU4 4ZX/2000000006/2003100012/2006200305#
IC-x00037N/Miss/DOD/Burke/272, Ambrose Lane/Cambridge/CB2 2XD/2005000003/2001100020#
IC-x00039A/Dr/X/Salter/285, Bannister Road/Sea Palling/SP2 6GW/2000000002/2005100029/2005200306#
IC-x00011I/MR/R/Reece/104, Bannister Lane/Cromer/CR0 6LD/2005000012/2003100001/2001200300#
IC-x00025V/Mr/P/Abbott/163, Drunk Lane/Hunstanton/HU1 1UR/2003000029/2004100017#
IC-x00008L/Dr/P/Runyon/150, Tick Tock Way/Swindon/SW8 4OJ/2004000005/2006100005/2001200316#
IC-x00028F/MR/X/Watt/267, Malton Road/Cambridge/CB4 1PQ/2004100016/2004200312#
IC-x00031X/Mr/S/Lorenz/276, Tick Tock Way/London/LN9 7ID/2005000023/2005100007#
IC-x00020C/Mr/LNV/Mcmillan/44, Drunk Street/London/LN6 1RG/2001000019#
IC-x00015H/Mr/TQZ/Dubose/201, Drunk Road/London/LN4 5RA/2003000026/2006100028/2000200307#

//Creates ClientsDetailsList from source file
public static ClientsDetailsList readFile(File inputFile) throws IOException{


ArrayList <String> clientData = new ArrayList<String>();
      ArrayList <ClientDetails> cdList = new ArrayList<>();
      ArrayList <PolicyList> arrayofPolsLists = new ArrayList<>();

      //Lists of ClientDetails fields
      ArrayList <Name> clientName = new ArrayList<>();
      ArrayList <String> clientID = new ArrayList<String>(); 
      ArrayList <Address> clientAddress = new ArrayList<>();


      // Lists of Name class fields
      ArrayList <String> clientTitle = new ArrayList<String>();
      ArrayList <String> clientInitials = new ArrayList<String>();
      ArrayList <String> clientSurname = new ArrayList<String>();


      //Lists of Address class fields
      ArrayList <String> clientStreet = new ArrayList<String>();
      ArrayList <String> clientCity = new ArrayList<String>();
      ArrayList <String> clientPostCode = new ArrayList<String>();

      ArrayList <ArrayList <Policy>> list = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Policy>>();


      Scanner fileScan = new Scanner(inputFile);
      fileScan.useDelimiter("#");


      int i =0;


      //Reading the file
      while(fileScan.hasNext()){
            clientData.add(fileScan.next());

                Scanner cdScan = new Scanner(clientData.get(i));
                cdScan.useDelimiter("/");

                ArrayList <String> tokens = new ArrayList<String>();
                ArrayList <Policy> clientPolicyNo = new ArrayList<>();

                while(cdScan.hasNext()){
                tokens.add(cdScan.next());
                }

                clientID.add(tokens.get(0));    
                clientTitle.add(tokens.get(1));
                clientInitials.add(tokens.get(2));
                clientSurname.add(tokens.get(3));
                clientStreet.add(tokens.get(4));        
                clientCity.add(tokens.get(5));
                clientPostCode.add(tokens.get(6));

                boolean whileController = true; 

                while(whileController){

                    clientPolicyNo.add(new Policy(tokens.get(7)));

                    switch(tokens.size()){
                    case 9 :  clientPolicyNo.add(new Policy(tokens.get(8)));                

                    break;
                    case 10:  clientPolicyNo.add(new Policy(tokens.get(8)));
                              clientPolicyNo.add(new Policy(tokens.get(9)));
                    break;
                    case 11:  clientPolicyNo.add(new Policy(tokens.get(8)));
                              clientPolicyNo.add(new Policy(tokens.get(9)));
                              clientPolicyNo.add(new Policy(tokens.get(10)));
                    break;
                    } 

                    whileController=false;
                }



                list.add(clientPolicyNo);


                i++;
       }      

      //Adding policy lists
      for(int j =0; j<clientID.size();j++){

          arrayofPolsLists.add(new PolicyList());
          arrayofPolsLists.get(j).aListOfPolicies=list.get(j);

      }



      //Creating Name objects
      for(int j =0;j<clientID.size();j++){
             clientName.add(new Name());

             clientName.get(j).Title = clientTitle.get(j);
             clientName.get(j).Initials = clientInitials.get(j);
             clientName.get(j).Surname = clientSurname.get(j);

         }

      //Creating Address objects
      for(int j =0;j<clientID.size();j++){
          clientAddress.add(new Address());

          clientAddress.get(j).street = clientStreet.get(j);
          clientAddress.get(j).city = clientCity.get(j);
          clientAddress.get(j).postcode = clientPostCode.get(j);

         }


      //Creating ClientDetails
      for(int j =0;j<clientID.size();j++){

         cdList.add(new ClientDetails());

         cdList.get(j).ClientID = clientID.get(j);
         cdList.get(j).fullName = clientName.get(j);  
         cdList.get(j).fullAddress = clientAddress.get(j);
         cdList.get(j).clientsPolicies = arrayofPolsLists.get(j); 

      }

      //Creating a ClientDetailsList object
      ClientsDetailsList ClientDetList = new ClientsDetailsList();
      ClientDetList.aListOfClientDetails = cdList;


      return ClientDetList;


}
```

ClientDetails class has 4 fields:

```
public String ClientID;
      public Name fullName;
      public Address fullAddress;
      public PolicyList clientsPolicies;
```

**Main method**

```
 File clientsFile = new File("ClientDetailsInput");
 InputData e = new InputData();

 ClientsDetailsList testList = new ClientsDetailsList();          
 testList = e.readFile(clientsFile);

 System.out.println(testList.getClientDetails("IC-x00013A"));
```

Comment: I don't see what is 'i'??

Comment: Why do you expect amethod that returns a single ClientDetails object to return more than one such object? You order one hamburger, you get one.

Comment: @laune At first, I also thought this was the problem, but after re-reading it seems that maybe the issue is, with subsequent calls to this method do not return the required result.

Comment: i is index, sorry syntax error.
The problem is that it returns only the first object. If I search by an ID of another object it returns null.

Comment: Make up your mind: do you xpect more than one match or don't you? "Only first object" indicates that you expect more than one object to be returned. If your current code returns null, there is no matching object.

Comment: I expect it to return Only one object (but not only the first). For example I want to return the second element with index(1) and it returns null when I search by its ID.

Comment: You might need to post the source for `ClientDetails`, consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: OK, the error is - as so often - elsewhere and not in the search loop. If it can't be found, it isn't there - see my previous comment ;-) and the updated answer.

Comment: You have an problem with your reading process...

Comment: I did not manage to find other ways of creating objects out of the file. Though I know that my syntax is not secure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a `break` after `found = true;`, for example...

```
public ClientDetails getClientDetails(String givenID) {
    boolean found = false;
    int index = 0;

    for(;index<aListOfClientDetails.size();index++){
        if((aListOfClientDetails.get(index).ClientID.equals(givenID))) {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }


    if(found)
        return aListOfClientDetails.get(index);
    else return null;

}
```

Or you could simplify it further, by doing away with the need for the `index` at all, for example

```
public ClientDetails getClientDetails(String givenID) {
    boolean found = false;
    int index = 0;
    ClientDetails details = null;

    for (ClientDetails check : aListOfClientDetails) {
        if(check.ClientID.equals(givenID)) {
            details = check;
            break;
        }
    }

    return details;
}
```

**Updated**

After actually been able to read the data, I added

```
String check = aListOfClientDetails.get(index).ClientID;
System.out.println(givenID + " = " + check);
if ((check.equals(givenID))) {
```

to the search list and it printed...

```
IC-x00013A = IC-x00042W
IC-x00013A = 
IC-x00033D
IC-x00013A = 
IC-x00013A
IC-x00013A = 
IC-x00018O
IC-x00013A = 
IC-x00037N
IC-x00013A = 
IC-x00039A
IC-x00013A = 
IC-x00011I
IC-x00013A = 
IC-x00025V
IC-x00013A = 
IC-x00008L
IC-x00013A = 
IC-x00028F
IC-x00013A = 
IC-x00031X
IC-x00013A = 
IC-x00020C
IC-x00013A = 
IC-x00015H
```

...which freaked me out, until I realised that the ID's were prefixed with a new line character...!

So what I did was add `trim` to each result from the `tokens` in the read method...

```
clientID.add(tokens.get(0).trim());
```

(I did it for each line, just haven't shown), which then lead to

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 13, Size: 13
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:638)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:414)
    at testsearch.TestSearch$ClientsDetailsList.getClientDetails(TestSearch.java:47)
    at testsearch.TestSearch.main(TestSearch.java:23)
```

Which is what I expected should happen in your search method...

If we have a closer look at the search loop...

```
for(;index<aListOfClientDetails.size();index++){
    if((aListOfClientDetails.get(index).ClientID.equals(givenID)))
        found = true;
}
```

You should be able to see, that regardless of the state of `found`, the `index` will ALWAYS be equal to `aListOfClientDetails.size()` at the end of the loop, as there is no other exit condition to the loop that takes `found` into consideration...

Which takes me back to my original suggestions...

Never discount the power of a simple `System.out.println` statement to check your sanity and a good debugger...

Comment: And using index instead of i (how does this compile??) might also be an improvement.

Comment: @laune I was focused on the return if statement and missed the `i`...I have no idea how it compiles, cause I don't have a runnable example ;)

Comment: maybe `if(check.ClientID.equals(givenID)) return check`

Comment: @ScaryWombat I'm old school, I believe in one entry and one exit point for my methods, clear and well defined and no possibility of missing a hidden `return` statement buried in some compound `if` statement somewhere

Answer (score 1):

Debugging would have helped i guess.

At the end you are returning

```
return aListOfClientDetails.get(i);
```

But you should get index "index" instead of "i" that was never initiated as far as i see.

So replace that with

```
return aListOfClientDetails.get(index);
```

And of course dont forget to leave the loop when you find something so index stays the right index.

Or just return the object right after you found it instead of setting found to true.

And last but not least: I dont know ClienID so I cant tell from here but if it does not implement the equals function the you actually will not get it work the way you want. So check what it does and perhaps override it.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the Scanner's delimiter to '#' or '/' causes the line separators `\n` (whatever it is on your system) to remain in the *data*. So, some `next()` method call will eventually produce a String value with a leading `\n`, which is bound to happen for all IDs from the second one up, if the line structure is aligned with the '#' signs.

The code you have for parsing is extremely complex. I'd advocate to read lines (\n-delimited) and handle one line at a time, using

```
String[] tokens = line.split( "/" );
```

and assigning the strings to the destination fields of one object. Avoid the many lists - this only confuses matters.